# Use RegEx to found and delete string after specific char

Tags: regex

I have a text file with hundreds of lines. Each line contains a string in this form

```
test/att/somePage.html: 18 / 18 / 0 / 0 / 0
```

I am trying to delete in each line, the `:` char and string after it. In this case the string to be delete is `: 18 / 18 / 0 / 0 / 0`. The `:` char is constant but the string after it could be different.

I though I will do that but creating a RegEx and use it within Sublime Text or Atom but I am struggling creating it. Do you have an Idea on how to achieve that?

I tried to use this `:[\s\S]*$` but it select all text and lines after the first `:`.

Comment: `[\s\S]` says all whitespace and all non-whitespace. Basically every character there is. So, yes, this will, when used with the greedy modifier `*` select everything until the end of the string ( `[\s\S]*` ).

Comment: So, if you want to just match stuff until the end of the line, use this instead `[^\r\n]*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all strings are formatted in the same way and the elements between `/` character are always numbers, you could try something like:

```
\:\s+\d+\s+\/\s+\d+\s+\/\s+\d+\s+\/\s+\d+\s+\/\s+\d+
```

Test and explanation here: https://regex101.com/r/NbGIab/1

Answer (score 1):

Use `:.*$` with `g` and `m` options to match and an empty string
as the replacement.

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/xXArky/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
:[0-9\/\s]*$
```

It catches all numbers, spaces and slashes in a line after the colon. Test here: https://regex101.com/r/xXArky/2